# Multiple Alias names for a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can we have multiple alias names for a single table?

Comment: Why would you want to?  Do you have a specific query that doesn't work?

Comment: for what you need that ?

Comment: Self joins or tables that live in multiple roles.  An example of the latter might be a date dimension table that joins to a fact table with several dates on it.

Comment: @Concerned, while there are several possible reasons that Dev could have for wanting to use multiple alias names, knowing the actual reason would help us give the best possible answer. It might even be for a requirement where multiple aliases are not the best possible answer.

Comment: A couple of the other comments were from people who didn't know why you might want multiple table aliases.  My examples were aimed at them.  Anyway, the OP accepted the answer so I guess he found it useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  You need to do this for a [self join,](http://databases.about.com/od/sql/a/selfjoins.htm) for example f you have a table storing a hierarchy:

```
create table Foo (
    FooID int
   ,ParentFooID int
   ,[columns]
)
```

You can do a join to get the children of parents that satisfy a particular condition with a query like:

```
Select b.*
  from Foo a
  join Foo b
    on a.FooID = b.ParentFooID
   and [some condition filtering a]
```

Comment: The query optimiser will have to do whatever is necessary to resolve the join predicate.  For example, if the table is large and has an index on ParentFooID, it will probably have to do index lookups to resolve the FooID - ParentFooID join.  Doing the match will always involve some resources.

Comment: We do this a lot (representing a heirarchy in SQL.) Performance is fine, and it's a good, flexible system - although the queries can get a little involved. It works. (p.s. good inference!)

Comment: Thanks a lot... really worked well for me... my problem was that I was putting the alias name before the table name....

Answer (score 5):

No, not on the same table, but you can select the same table twice and give each a different alias.

```
SELECT alias1.*, alias2.*
FROM mytable alias1, mytable alias2
```

This will then allow you to use the same table for a different purpose within a single query.

Comment: Yes, if you select the table twice then it will have to do twice as much work. Performance will depend on how they are used, what they are joined two and the indexes and statistics available to the query optimizer.

Comment: Since Chris's query has no join condition (implicit or explict) a cartesian join would be expected - ie. every single row in table will be linked with all the rows in the same table, so if you had 20 rows in table your resultset would be 400 rows! This is much worse than twice as much work. However, it's not the aliases that are causing the work - it's the cartesian join.

Comment: The cross join was just an example to which I wasn't referring to when answering the comment - the OP did not specify how he was going to use the tables, I'd assume he will either self join or join them to different tables. Like I said performance will depend on how they are used.